# Getting WTSSessionId in a Java program

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the value of the WTSSessionID parameter in a Java program. I am wondering if JNI is the only way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, the answer to any question asking "...is JNI the only way?" is: No, it is not the only way.  There are at least two alternatives to JNI.  I've used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/); there's another one called [JNative](http://jnative.free.fr/SPIP-v1-8-3/article.php3?id_article=4); and who knows, there might be others.  The advantage of these alternatives is that you don't have to create a new dll to act as a shim between Java and the native API.

Comment: One might argue that these are all JNI, just rendered more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% Java way to obtain this Windows-specific value. You can execute a program and capture its output, or you can use JNI. You can use JNI with a DLL you write yourself, or you can use JNI with a tool (e.g. Jacob, JNA, or JNative), but in any of those cases you are invoking native code.